# Congruences of modular forms modulo other modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, congruences

Congruences between modular forms are certainly a big topic in number theory, maybe with 
$$E_{p-1}\equiv 1 \mod p \qquad \text{for a prime }p\geq 5$$
as the easiest example. Sometimes, $p$ might be replaced by a more general natural number. But one could equally well replace $p$ also by another modular form like the discriminant $\Delta$ or an Eisenstein series $E_n$ or consider congruences modulo an ideal like $(p, E_n)$.

Edit: In concrete terms, two modular forms $f$ and $g$ for some congruence group $\Gamma$ are congruent to each other modulo $E_n$ if $f-g = cE_n$ for some modular form $c$ (for the same congruence subgroup).

> 1) Is there any source where such congruences are considered?
>
> 2) If not, is there any reason why these are not interesting?

Comment: Normally one considers congruences of modular forms with each other modulo some ideal $I$ in a coefficient ring $R$, which means each Fourier coefficient (in $R$), or possibly each Hecke eigenvalue (in $R$), is congruence mod $I$.  Are you saying you want to consider  congruences of the form $f \equiv g mod (h)$ which means $h = c(f-g)$ where $f, g, h$ are modular forms (and maybe $c$ is too)?  Can you make your question more precise?